# How can I destructure with a vector from a var

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I want to do this

```
(let [[a b c] '(1 2 3)]
  {:a a :b b :c c}) ;; gives {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

But with `[a b c]` saved in a vector like this

```
(def vect '[a b c])
(let [vect '(1 2 3)]
  {:a a :b b :c c}) ;; complains that a is unresolved
```

Is it possible to somehow use a var to define how to destructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs, because in this snippet:

```
(let [vect '(1 2 3)]
   {:a a :b b :c c})
```

You're binding `vect` to `'(1 2 3)`. The `vect` earlier defined as `'[a b c]` earlier will be shadowed by the local let binding. `a`,`b` and `c` will be left unbound.

The only way I think you can do what you ask is by using (*abusing?*) eval/macros, and building up the exact form that you need.

```
(eval (list 'let [vect ''(1 2 3)] '{:a a :b b :c c}))
;; => {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```

However, I really urge you to put in some [hammock time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f84n5oFoZBc) here and think about why you need to destructure using a var, and possible alternative designs. The solution above is already pretty hacky and using it could get very ugly...

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Daniel to possibly rethink the reason *why* you need to do it, e.g. what exactly the problem is you are after.

But if you insist :), pretending that we literally work with "a b c.."s, you can do this:

```
user=> (def xs '[a b c])
#'user/xs

user=> (into {} (for [v xs] [(keyword v) v]))
{:a a, :b b, :c c}
```